# Angular HttpClient mapping response to Model Class

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi. 
I am trying to map a response to a model class, using the new HttpClient. 
But it seems that my response never ends up having the functions from the model class.

I understand that this is not the correct way of doing it, but how would one go about mapping a response to a model class?

The get from my Api-service:

```
  listSimple(): Observable<Array<Airport>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Airport>>(this.airportUrl + 'list')
  }
```

The use in the component:

```
  getAirports(){
    this.airportApi.listSimple().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.airportList = res;
        console.log("Airport list: ", res);
      },
      err => {
        //@TODO Incorporate global error handeling and remove this
        console.error("An error occoured while fetching the airport list!");
      });
  }
```

The model class:

```
export interface Inms {
    get_name:Function;
    get_value:Function;
    get_children:Function;
}

export class Airport implements Inms{
  IATA:string;
  name:string;
  trips:number;
  children:any;

  constructor(){ }

  public get_name() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public get_value() {
    return this.IATA;
  }

  public get_children() {
    return this.children? this.children : null;
  }

}
```

Where I ty to use the function get_children this is the result:

```
_v.context.$implicit.get_children is not a function
```

**My solution:**
This is how I ended op handling the mapping, please let me know if there is any better or alternative solutions!

```
  //Returns a simplifyed list of all airports
  listSimple(): Observable<Array<Airport>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<Airport>>(this.airportUrl + 'list')
      .map(array => array
        .map(airport => new Airport(airport.IATA, airport.name, airport.trips))
      )
  }
```

Comment: That's perfectly normal and expected. JSON.parse() (called by HttpClient) doesn't know about your classes. It creates POJOs matching with the received JSON. By telling TypeScript that it returns an Array<Airport>>, you're just lying to yourself (and paying the consequences later).

Comment: Okay, I see. What would be a correct way to map the response to my model class?

Comment: Iterate through the array of POJOs, and transform each of them to an Airport, using `new Airport()`, and copying all the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I enden op doing it using .map and iterating as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
export interface IAirport {
  IATA:string;
  name:string;
  trips:number;
  children:any;
}
// then
listSimple(): Observable<IAirport[]> {
    return this.http.get<IAirport[]>(this.airportUrl + 'list')
  }
```